# How to fix navbar with bootstrap 3 to use with bootstrap 4 with dropdown menu item and sitemap

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, navbar, sitemap

I'm trying to use menu control with bootstrap 4 and Sitemap for admin and user. i have menu dll code but it is using bootstrap 3. I cannot add dropdown menu in navigation bar. How do i do it? I have tried with changing HTML Tag, but it didn't work.How to convert This Code so it can work with bootstrap 4 and dropdown can generate

```
[ControlValueProperty("SelectedValue")]
[DefaultEvent("MenuItemClick")]
[SupportsEventValidation]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:BootstrapMenu runat=\"server\"></{0}:BootstrapMenu>")]
public sealed class BootstrapMenu : Menu
{
private const string hightlightActiveKey = "HighlightActive";
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the header text over the left list box.
    /// </summary>
[Browsable(true)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
[DefaultValue(false)]
[DisplayName("HighlightActive")]
public bool HighlightActive
{
get { return this.ViewState[hightlightActiveKey] != null && Convert.ToBoolean(this.ViewState[hightlightActiveKey]); }
set { this.ViewState[hightlightActiveKey] = value; }
}

public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
 // don't call base.RenderBeginTag()
}

public override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
// don't call base.RenderEndTag()
}

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
// don't call base.OnPreRender(e);
this.EnsureDataBound();
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
this.BuildItems(writer, this.Items, true);
}

protected override void EnsureDataBound()
{
base.EnsureDataBound();
}

private void BuildItems(HtmlTextWriter writer, MenuItemCollection items, bool isRoot = false)
{

if (items.Count <= 0)
   {
   return;
   }



string cssClass = "dropdown-menu";

   if (isRoot)
   {
   cssClass = "nav navbar-nav";
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CssClass))
   {
   cssClass += " " + this.CssClass;
   }
   }



writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, cssClass);
   writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Ul);

   foreach (MenuItem item in items)
        {
            this.BuildItem(writer, item);
        }

        writer.RenderEndTag(); // </ul>
    }

    private void BuildItem(HtmlTextWriter writer, MenuItem item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
        }

        if (writer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
        }

        if (item.ChildItems.Count > 0)
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "dropdown");    
        }

        if (this.IsLink(item))
        {
            if (this.HighlightActive && this.Page.ResolveUrl(item.NavigateUrl) == this.Page.Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
            {
                writer.AddAttribute("class", "active");
            }

            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Li);
            this.RenderLink(writer, item);
        }
        else if (this.HasChildren(item))
        {
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Li);
            this.RenderDropDown(writer, item);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Li);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A);
            writer.Write(item.Text);
            writer.RenderEndTag();
        }

        writer.RenderEndTag(); // </li>
    }

    private bool HasChildren(MenuItem item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
        }

        return item.ChildItems.Count > 0;
    }

    private bool IsLink(MenuItem item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
        }

        return item.Enabled && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.NavigateUrl);
    }

    private void RenderLink(HtmlTextWriter writer, MenuItem item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
        }

        if (writer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
        }

        string href = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.NavigateUrl)
                ? this.Page.Server.HtmlEncode(this.ResolveClientUrl(item.NavigateUrl))
                : this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(
                    this,
                    "b" + item.ValuePath.Replace(this.PathSeparator.ToString(), "\\"),
                    true);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, href);

        string toolTip = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ToolTip)
            ? item.ToolTip
            : item.Text;
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Title, toolTip);

        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A);
        writer.Write(item.Text);
        writer.RenderEndTag(); // </a>
    }

    private void RenderDropDown(HtmlTextWriter writer, MenuItem item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
        }

        if (writer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
        }
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, "#");
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "dropdown-toggle");
        writer.AddAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A);
        string anchorValue = item.Text + "&nbsp;";
        writer.Write(anchorValue);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "caret");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.B);
        writer.RenderEndTag(); // </b>          
        writer.RenderEndTag(); // </a>
        this.BuildItems(writer, item.ChildItems);
    }
}
```

This Code is for Navigation bar 
``

```
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
<a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/" style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:22px; font-weight:500;">Application</a>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<jk:BootstrapMenu ID="BootstrapMenu1" runat="server" DataSourceId="SiteMapDataSource1" />
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="False" />
</ul>
<asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
<AnonymousTemplate>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a runat="server" href="~/Register">Register</a></li>
<li><a runat="server" href="~/Login">Log in</a></li>
</ul>
</AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
</div>
</div>
```

Sitemap

```
<siteMapNode title="Home"  description="" roles="*" >
    <siteMapNode url="~/Home" title="Home" description="" roles="*"/>

    <siteMapNode url="javascript:;" title="Admin" description="Admin Page" roles ="Admin">
      <siteMapNode url ="~/Admin/Roles" title="Roles" description="Roles"/>
    </siteMapNode>

    <siteMapNode url="~/About" title="About"  description="" roles="*"/>
    <siteMapNode url="~/Contact" title="Contact"  description="" roles="*"/></siteMapNode>
```

Output

[Output of Navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyDzL.jpg)

In sitemap I have created childItem Under Admin Menu, but It cannot seen in Output. In output Only Parent Menu is showing. C# code is generating HTML format of menu Using css class of bootstrap version 3. I need help to change css Class of bootstrap 3 into bootstrap 4 version

Comment: "...but it didn't work..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: I hope now you get my point